# I am trying to draw a bar chart on a vf page using remoteaction method that returns a json response

Tags: apex, visualforce, charts, remote-action

Need help figuring why my results list is blank coming from a json response when building a chart on my vf page. Any help is greatly appreciated.
Below is my controller:

```
global with sharing class ChartController {
  public List<ProdCatYOYWrapper> listofProdCatYOYRecords {get;set;}
/**
  Loads JSON response
*/
@RemoteAction    
  global Static List<object> loadOpps() {
    system.debug('SPD----in loadOpps');

    List<ProdCatYOYWrapper> listofProdCatYOYRecords;
    listofProdCatYOYRecords = new List<ProdCatYOYWrapper>();
    Map<String, Object> JSONDeserializeMap;
    Map<String, Object> JSONDeserializeMap2; 
    List<Object> resultsList; 
    Map<String, Object> fieldsMap;
    Map<String, Object> FieldMapsPCYOY;

    Http http = new Http(); // Create a new http object to send the request object
    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();            
    system.debug('SPD ProdCatYOYController.populateProdCatYOYStat() CALLING req = new HttpRequest');
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(); 
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); //Set header of request sent
    req.setHeader('Accept','*/*');
    req.setMethod('GET');  
    req.setTimeout(120000); //Setting time out to Maximum to avoid read time out error
    Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf('<UID>' +':' +'<PSWD>' );
    String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
    req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);

    String endPoint = ('https://qas.gw.apps.hdsupply.com/sap/opu/odata/sap/Y_ZSDSLC03_SU_Q002_1_SRV/Y_ZSDSLC03_SU_Q002_1(YMER_VAR_PDT_MULT_OPT=\'\',A0I_FPER=\'2016001\',A0I_FPERTo=\'2016012\',YMER_VAR_CUST_SO_OPT=\'0000004520\',YMER_VAR_CUST_SO_OPTTo=\'0000004520\')/Results?$format=json&$orderby=A0MATERIAL__ZPRODH1_T+DESC');
    req.setEndPoint(endpoint);
    res = http.send(req);
    system.debug('SPD res.getBody(): ' + res.getBody());
    JSONDeserializeMap = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
    JSONDeserializeMap2 = (Map<String, Object>)JSONDeserializeMap.get('d');
    resultsList = (List<Object>)JSONDeserializeMap2.get('results');
    fieldsMap = new Map<String, Object>();
    FieldMapsPCYOY = new Map<String, Object>();
    for (Object o : resultsList) {  
                        ProdCatYOYWrapper ProdCat = new ProdCatYOYWrapper();
                        fieldsMap = (Map<String, Object>) o;
                        //ProdCat.CustomerId = string.valueOf(fieldsMap.get('A0SOLD_TO'));
                        //ProdCat.CustomerName = string.valueOf(fieldsMap.get('A0SOLD_TO_T'));
                        //ProdCat.FiscalPeriod = string.valueOf(fieldsMap.get('A0FISCPER'));
                        ProdCat.ProductHierarchy = string.valueOf(fieldsMap.get('A0MATERIAL__ZPRODH1_T'));

                        ProdCat.Spend = string.valueOf(fieldsMap.get('A00O2TGSP7SUV1BLKTSHARDZXQ'));

                        listofProdCatYOYRecords.add(ProdCat);
                        //FieldMapsPCYOY.put(ProdCat.ProductHierarchy, ProdCat.Spend);
    }
    system.debug('SPD listofProdCatYOYRecords: ' + listofProdCatYOYRecords);
    system.debug('SPD FieldMapsPCYOY: ' + FieldMapsPCYOY);
    system.debug('SPD resultsList: ' + resultsList);
    if(listofProdCatYOYRecords.size() != 0){                    
      return listofProdCatYOYRecords;
      //return FieldMapsPCYOY;
      //return resultsList;
    }else {
      return null;
    }
  }
  //*****************************************************************************
  // Wrapper to hold fields  
  //*****************************************************************************    
   public class ProdCatYOYWrapper {
        //public string FiscalPeriod {get;set;} //A0FISCPER
        public string ProductHierarchy {get;set;} //A0MATERIAL__ZPRODH1_T
        public string Spend {get;set;} //A00O2TGSP7SUV1BLKTSHARDZXQ
       //public string CustomerName {get;set;} //A0SOLD_TO_T        
        //public string CustomerId {get;set;} //A0SOLD_TO         
    }    
}
```

and my VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="ChartController" sidebar="false"> 
<!-- Google API inclusion -->
<apex:includeScript id="a" value="https://www.google.com/jsapi" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(initCharts);

    function initCharts() {
        ChartController.loadOpps( 
             function(result, event){ 

                alert('In function');
                alert('result: ' + result);
                alert('event: ' + event);
                 // load Column chart
                 var visualization = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chartBlock'));


                 // Prepare table model for chart with columns
                 var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

                 //data.addColumn('string', 'fiscalperiod');
                 data.addColumn('string', 'ProductHierarchy');
                 data.addColumn('number', 'Spend');   
                 // add rows from the remoting results
                 //loop through JSON total period sales to build initial chart 
                 for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
                    var r = result[i];
                    data.addRow([r.ProductHierarchy, r.Spend]);
                  }

                // all done, lets draw the chart with some options to make it look nice.
                visualization.draw(data, {legend : {position: 'top', textStyle: {color: 'blue', fontSize: 10}}, width:window.innerWidth,vAxis:{textStyle:{fontSize: 10}},hAxis:{textStyle:{fontSize: 10},showTextEvery:1,slantedText:false}});
          }, {escape:true});
      } 
</script>

<apex:sectionHeader title="ProdCat YOY" subtitle="Demo"/>

<!-- Google Charts will be drawn in this DIV -->
<div id="chartBlock" />

</apex:page>
```

Comment: Did you check to make sure you got a valid response? According to your code, you're returning null when there's no results, so ...

Comment: Yes i am getting a response: SPD listofProdCatYOYRecords: (ProdCatYOYWrapper:[ProductHierarchy=Tools, Spend=4.49], ProdCatYOYWrapper:[ProductHierarchy=Textiles, Spend=311.40], ProdCatYOYWrapper:[ProductHierarchy=Safety Products, Spend=17.99], ProdCatYOYWrapper:[ProductHierarchy=Office Solutions, Spend=17.99], ProdCatYOYWrapper:[ProductHierarchy=Office Solutions, Spend=4.39], ProdCatYOYWrapper:[ProductHierarchy=Office Solutions, Spend=8.79], ProdCatYOYWrapper:[ProductHierarchy=Office Solutions, Spend=60.49],

Comment: @sfdcfox my result and event when alerted from my page only show:result: [object Object]

Comment: I would expect that. Try alert(JSON.stringify(result)) instead.

Comment: That returns the values but the chart still does not show any value? I did add var json = JSON.stringify(result);  alert(json);     and                            
                    for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
                    var r = json[i];
                    data.addRow([r.ProductHierarchy, r.Spend]); 
                    //data.addRow([r.Name, r.ExpectedRevenue, r.Amount]);
                  }

Answer (score 0):

The result from a Visualforce Remoting Event isn't a real Array. You can use the `for(x in y)` syntax, or read from the keys. The following change should work:

```
for(var i = 0; i < Object.keys(result).length; i++) {
```

Comment: that didnt seem to work either: i still get result: [object Object],[object Object] and i changed the code to be: for(var i = 0; i < object.keys(result).length; i++) {
                    var r = result[i];
                    data.addRow([r.ProductHierarchy, r.Spend]); 
                  } and now my chart doesnt show up at all?

Comment: @user45581 Hmm, from the JSON.stringify I suggested earlier, what did the output look like? Odds are there's some additional wrapping going on.

Comment: i believe you are right. I added result = JSON.stringify(result); and get back: result: [{"ProductHierarchy":"Tools","Spend":"4.49"},{"ProductHierarchy":"Textiles","Spend":"311.40"},

Comment: please let me know what else to look at as I am still not getting the values or the chart back.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to get my code working and see the values in the chart now:
Below is the working code.
VF Page:

// Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(initCharts);

    function initCharts() {
        ChartController.loadOpps( 
             function(result, event){ 
                result = JSON.stringify(result);

                result = result.split('[').join('');
                result = result.split(']').join('');
                result = result.split('},{').join('}~{');
                result = result.split('~');

                 // load Column chart
                 var visualization = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chartBlock'));


                 // Prepare table model for chart with columns
                 var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();     

                 data.addColumn('string', 'FiscalPeriod');
                 //data.addColumn('string', 'ProductHierarchy');
                 data.addColumn('number', 'Spend');   
                 // add rows from the remoting results
                 for(var i = 0; i

VF Controller:
global with sharing class ChartController {
  public List listofProdCatYOYRecords {get;set;}

/******************************************************
* Constructor
******************************************************/ 
    public ChartController(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        //system.debug('THJ in OrderStatusController CONSTRUCTOR controller: ' + controller);
        //PAGE_SIZE = integer.valueOf(System.Label.OrderStatus_PAGE_SIZE);
        //currentPageIndex=0;
        //Apexpages.currentPage().getHeaders().put('X-UA-Compatible', 'IE=8');
        //this.account = (Account)controller.getRecord();
        //System.debug('SPD in ProdCatYOYController this.account: ' + this.account.id); 
        //    String custId = [select Customer_ID__c from Account where id = :account.Id].Customer_ID__c;
        //    System.debug('SPD in ProdCatYOYController custId: ' + custId);
        //    customerId = string.valueOf(custId).leftPad(10,'0');
        //    System.debug('SPD in ProdCatYOYController customerId: ' + customerId);
    }

/**
  Loads most recent 10 Opportunities
*/
@RemoteAction
  global Static List loadOpps() {
    system.debug('SPD----in loadOpps');

```
//return [select Id, Name, ExpectedRevenue, Amount from Opportunity order by CreatedDate DESC limit 10];

List<ProdCatYOYWrapper> listofProdCatYOYRecords;
listofProdCatYOYRecords = new List<ProdCatYOYWrapper>();
Map<String, Object> JSONDeserializeMap;
Map<String, Object> JSONDeserializeMap2; 
List<Object> resultsList; 
Map<String, Object> fieldsMap;
Map<String, Object> FieldMapsPCYOY;

Http http = new Http(); // Create a new http object to send the request object
HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();            
system.debug('SPD ProdCatYOYController.populateProdCatYOYStat() CALLING req = new HttpRequest');
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(); 
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); //Set header of request sent
req.setHeader('Accept','*/*');
req.setMethod('GET');  
req.setTimeout(120000); //Setting time out to Maximum to avoid read time out error
Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf('<UID>' +':' +'<PSwd>' );
String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);

String endPoint = ('https://qas.gw.apps.hdsupply.com/sap/opu/odata/sap/Y_ZSDSLC03_SU_Q002_1_SRV/Y_ZSDSLC03_SU_Q002_1(YMER_VAR_PDT_MULT_OPT=\'\',A0I_FPER=\'2016001\',A0I_FPERTo=\'2016012\',YMER_VAR_CUST_SO_OPT=\'0000004520\',YMER_VAR_CUST_SO_OPTTo=\'0000004520\')/Results?$format=json&$orderby=A0FISCPER+DESC');
req.setEndPoint(endpoint);
res = http.send(req);
system.debug('SPD res.getBody(): ' + res.getBody());
JSONDeserializeMap = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
JSONDeserializeMap2 = (Map<String, Object>)JSONDeserializeMap.get('d');
resultsList = (List<Object>)JSONDeserializeMap2.get('results');
fieldsMap = new Map<String, Object>();
FieldMapsPCYOY = new Map<String, Object>();
for (Object o : resultsList) {  
                    ProdCatYOYWrapper ProdCat = new ProdCatYOYWrapper();
                    fieldsMap = (Map<String, Object>) o;
                    //ProdCat.CustomerId = string.valueOf(fieldsMap.get('A0SOLD_TO'));
                    //ProdCat.CustomerName = string.valueOf(fieldsMap.get('A0SOLD_TO_T'));
                    ProdCat.FiscalPeriod = string.valueOf(fieldsMap.get('A0FISCPER'));
                    //ProdCat.ProductHierarchy = string.valueOf(fieldsMap.get('A0MATERIAL__ZPRODH1_T'));

                    ProdCat.Spend = string.valueOf(fieldsMap.get('A00O2TGSP7SUV1BLKTSHARDZXQ'));

                    listofProdCatYOYRecords.add(ProdCat);
                    //FieldMapsPCYOY.put(ProdCat.ProductHierarchy, ProdCat.Spend);
}
system.debug('SPD listofProdCatYOYRecords: ' + listofProdCatYOYRecords);
system.debug('SPD FieldMapsPCYOY: ' + FieldMapsPCYOY);
system.debug('SPD resultsList: ' + resultsList);
if(listofProdCatYOYRecords.size() != 0){                    
  return listofProdCatYOYRecords;
  //return FieldMapsPCYOY;
  //return resultsList;
}else {
  return null;
}
```

}
  //*****************************************************************************
  // Wrapper to all Order Status fields
  //*****************************************************************************
   public class ProdCatYOYWrapper {
        public string FiscalPeriod {get;set;} //A0FISCPER
        //public string ProductHierarchy {get;set;} //A0MATERIAL__ZPRODH1_T
        public string Spend {get;set;} //A00O2TGSP7SUV1BLKTSHARDZXQ
       //public string CustomerName {get;set;} //A0SOLD_TO_T
        //public string CustomerId {get;set;} //A0SOLD_TO
    }
}